# php $_POST variable as column name in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a dropdown menu and wish to use the variable so acquired to select a column in MySQL query. I have used the following code:

```
<select name="selectedvalue">
    <option value="n1">Birthweight</option>
    <option value="n2">3-month weight</option>
    <option value="n3">6-month weight</option>

</select>
```

Later I am retrieving the variable using

```
$selval = ($_POST['selectedvalue']);
```

MySQL query:

```
$lambings = "Select year, `".($_POST['selectedvalue'])."` as weight from mytable 
      GROUP by year(dob)";
```

but the sql query fails every time.

Comment: print what is inside your `$selval` or `$_POST['selectedvalue']`?

Comment: And provide __error text__.

Comment: What are the actual column names?

Comment: If you `print($lambings);exit;` and copy/paste the query does it run via phpMyAdmin or mysql-workbench, etc. ?

Comment: Do you execute `$lambings`? What driver are you using? This is open to SQL injections.

Comment: I am using a dropdown, is it still prone to MySQL injections? @user3783243

Comment: @RachelWatson Yes, a user doesn't even need to use the form. They could run a `curl` to your form's `action`'s value and send any value they want. Rough example `curl --data "selectedvalue=n1\` union all select password from users where role='admin'--" http://example.com/process.php`

Comment: mysql_escape_string will help? @user3783243

Comment: @RachelWatson Nope, you are passing a column name, not a value. You need to check that value against a whitelist of valid column names. Use `in_array` and create an array of column names. (Also if you are using the `mysql_` driver you should stop that, you wont be able to use parameterized queries which is what should be used when you are passing values)

Comment: @user3783243 I am new to programming, could you suggest an e-resource which would help me find out more?

Comment: Take a look at this thread, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php, and this answer for your current example https://stackoverflow.com/a/8255054/3783243

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not the variable, but the query itself. You can use `group by` only when you have `count/ averages` etc in your query.

either change that or remove the `group by` part in your query.

Comment: Yes that was it! Thanks very much